# How to echo custom text field attribute instead of product url

Tags: php, html, magento

I'm trying to echo a custom text field attribute into a url link.

I have a CMS page with URL key "my-page" so I have created a text field called "cmspageid" for a product and added the URL key "my-page" into the text filed.

Here's the whole script:

```
<div class="new-product-content">
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
    <h3 class="subtitle new-products"><?php echo $this->__('HOT PRODUCTS') ?></h3>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>

    <ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <li class="thumb<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(175) ?>" width="175" height="175" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
            </a>
               <div class="caption">    
                  <h4 class="product-name"> <?php $_productName = $this->helper('core/string')->truncate($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()),20,'...', $_remainder, true); ?>
                   <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productName ?>">
                    <?php echo $_productName ?><?php echo $this->__('&#8482;'); ?></a></h4>
                     <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="desc">                  
                    <?php $sdesc = $_product->getShortDescription();
                    $sdesc = trim($sdesc);
                    $limit = 180;
                    if (strlen($sdesc) > $limit) {
                        $sdesc = substr($sdesc, 0, strrpos(substr($sdesc, 0, $limit), ' '));
                    } ?>
                    <?php echo $sdesc."..."; ?>
                  </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Order now...') ?></button>
  <button class="btn-link" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('More info') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('More info?') ?></button>

      </li>
      <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>  
<?php endif ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j('.thumb li').last().css('border-right', 'none');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need include cmspageid  instead of getProductUrl:

```
  <button class="btn-link" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('More info') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?><?php echo $_product->getCmspageid() ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('More info?') ?></button>
```

So when the link is clicked the correct CMS page loads.

If anyone can give us a hand I'd be very grateful.

Many thanks

Comment: You need call the URL based on your custom attribute from product?

Comment: yes instead of calling the product URL i.e mysite.com/myproduct.html I would like to echo the value from the text field i.e mysite.com/mycustomattribute this is because the url key for my CMS page will be added to the custom attribute text field so the CMS page will load... Hope that makes sense?

Comment: By default that field is not add to the data, You will need to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604222/show-product-attributes-in-list-phtml-magento or you could also do it in you xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was somehow getting the attribute text as part of the URL foreach product. Since I was using the catalog/product_new I couldn't echo the attribute text as Magento only allows attribute to be displayed on catalog/product_view pages!

I had to modify the new.php file at line 114 adding this line:

->addAttributeToSelect('cmspageid')

Then in the new.phtml file where I have the "More info" button I echoed the value from 'cmspageid'

> __('More info') ?>" onclick="setLocation('getCmspageid(); ?>')">__('More info?')
>   ?>

Now I have an "Order now" button and a "More info" button for each product. When "More info" is clicked the user will go to a CMS Page showing full details for that product...

Phew!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that:

```
<a href="{{store url=""}}<?php echo $_product->getCmspageid() ?>">Link Here</a>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I believe we a very close I've ammended the code but the page just reloads itself see above^ code edit

Comment: On your product cmspageid you need save exactly the cms page reference.

Comment: @R.S I have done somthing similar where I created a videoid attribute using a text field and just echoed it in the URL to show youtube videos on a CMS page `<a class="fancybox-video" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideoid(); ?>"></a>` The same method should apply I believe but I can't get it to work????

Comment: You can do something like that: Mage::Helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($_product->getCmspageid())

Comment: Where am I placing your code? At the top of page or as part of the URL?

Comment: You put this conde on your href. <a href="<?php echo Mage::Helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($_product->getCmspageid()) ?>">link</a>

Comment: @user1704524 Was this $_product->getVideoid() on the product view or product listing page?

Comment: @R.S it is on a product CMS page and echoes the videoid for each productid

Comment: @Guerra Page reloads itself with this code:`<button class="btn-link" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('More info') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::Helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($_product->getCmspageid()) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('More info?') ?></button>` Do I need to call the getCmspageid inside the foreach loop?

Comment: depends, need to see what you saving inside this attribute. If you just saving the cmspageid string, you don't need foreach. else you need manipulate the information for your propous.

Comment: I can see the value for the custom attribute when I go to the product view page. attributes.phtml echoes the attribute if its set to visible on the frontend. Still baffled why it wont show up else where.

Comment: You should create CMS alias to your phtml file, and in your cmspageid you save the CMS alias.

Comment: Issue solved I followed the instructions from here [link]http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/displaying-magento-custom-attributes-frontend[\link]

Comment: Like I said earlier the cms id wasn't included in your select field name... you could also do something like `<action method="addAttribute"><code>cmspageid</code></action>` in the xml