# Magento getAttribute is not working in list.phtml?

Tags: php, magento

This is magento code that i have used to get attribute.

```
  echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attrcode')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

This code is working fine in `view.phtml` it return to attribute code value.

when i write same code in `list.phtml` file this code is return `blank`.

where i do mistake. please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('attrcode');?>
```

please use that code on list page and also check attribute setting in ('Used in Product Listing': "Yes")

Comment: I had the same problem and your "Check attribute setting 'Used in Product Listing' = Yes" made the difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code get attribute name and value that that doesn't belongs to any product

```
$attributeCode = 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE';

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', $attributeCode);

$attribute = $productCollection->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
print_r($attribute->getData()); // print out the available attributes

$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
print_r($options);
```

Comment: i already try this code but not working for me please check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604222/show-product-attributes-in-list-phtml-magento

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the values of a specific attribute in Magento 2 phtml file, then use following code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product','attribute_code');
$values = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```